# How do I add pagination to JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, pagination

I have a GET request that loads several thousand lines from a CSV.  I get all the rows out of it and covert it to a hash.

My GET request method that looks like this

```
def index 

 rows = []
  CSV.foreach('test.csv', headers: true) do |row|
    rows << row.to_hash
   json_data = rows.to_json #converts all of the rows to JSON data
    @users = json_data
end
```

I can display this json data in the DOM, however that takes a long time to load. I've tried the will_paginate gem that defaults it to 25 entries per page. That works fine, however it is still loading all the data at once with pagination headers.

So, how can I do this so that it ONLY loads 25 rows of json for page one, then when I select page 2 it loads the next 25, so on and so on until I've gone through all the data?

Appreciate any help from you Ruby/JSON wizards out there

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari can paginate arbitrary arrays:

```
@paginatable_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(rows).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Do that to your `rows` array before you convert it to json (because it needs to be an array).

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Now will this load all my data at once? Or will it load just the first 25 rows, then the next 25 when selecting page 2? Thus not killing my server trying to load everything

Comment: ok that sort of works. It does return pagination of my data. But it does a call all at once! I just want it to make the call for the first 25 rows. That's it. Then after I click Next it will make a call and fetch the next 25 rows.

How do people handle large sets of data? If you're reading in a query with thousands of rows, how do you only get a section at a time instead of waiting for ALL of the data to be returned?

Comment: The CSV lib you're using has other methods that allow you to get just the right amount of lines. But you have to calculate which line to start from depending on your current page. The formula is: `(page - 1) * per + 1`